# Custom close button inside the header of StackNavigator of React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm currently working with React Native and there I've got a question about React Navigation and the `StackNavigator`. I would like to add a custom close button to the header, but I'm not sure how to do this.

It's just possible for me to navigate to the screens, but not for example to go back or dispatch something.

On my example the `navigationOptions` for the `HomeScreen` is working. The drawer opens and the `SettingsButton` navigates to the settings screen. But I've got problems with the `navigationOptions` of the `EntryScreen`. There I build a `CloseButton` to go back, but I need access to the navigation object.

With `navigate` it's possible to navigate to other screens, but I need access to the parent object `navigation`. For example on the class for the drawer it's possible to get access through `props.navigation` (For example `props.navigation.navigate('Home')` or `props.navigation.goBack(null)`)

This is a part of my current code. Of course it's currently not working because of the missing access to `navigation`:

```
const Stack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: ({ navigate }) => ({
        left: <DrawerButton navigate={navigate} />,
        right: <SettingsButton navigate={navigate} />
      })
    }
  },
  Entry: {
    screen: EntryScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: ({ navigation }) => ({
        right: <CloseButton navigate={navigation } />
      })
    }
  }
})

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Stack
  }},
  {
    contentComponent: HamburgerMenu
  }
)
```

These are the buttons:

```
export const CloseButton = (props) => {
  let testButton = <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack(null)}>
    <Icon name='close' style={styles.headerButtonIcon} />
  </TouchableHighlight>
  return testButton 
}

export const SettingsButton = (props) => (
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.navigate('Settings')}>
    <Icon name='more-vert' style={styles.headerButtonIcon} />
  </TouchableHighlight>
)
```

Maybe you can help me there. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer thanks to the help of sigmazen on Github.

Instead of `navigation` I have to put `goBack` into the header for the CloseButton. After this I'm able to use it through `props.goBack(null)`

```
Entry: {
    screen: EntryScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: `Eintrag`,
      header: ({ goBack }) => ({
        right: <CloseButton goBack={goBack} />
      })
    }
  },


export const CloseButton = (props) => {
  let test = <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.goBack(null)}>
    <Icon name='close' style={styles.headerButtonIcon} />
  </TouchableHighlight>

  return test
}
```